# What is Cluster, dissimilarity and distance in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-science

I am watching MIT OpenCourseWare 6.0002 clustering video and I do not understand some code from that class.

What is this `.Cluster` ?

```
for e in initialCentroids:
        clusters.append(cluster.Cluster([e]))
```

What is `.distance`?

```
  for e in examples:
            smallestDistance = e.distance(clusters[0].getCentroid())
```

What is `.dissimilarity`?

```
 minDissimilarity = cluster.dissimilarity(best)
```

From the code I can understand what they are doing, but I would like to more detail about it. Related document would be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you could tell what module are they part of? Are they part of scikit?

Comment: No. They actually did not use any library @ThatBird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are terms mainly to describe data and it's relationship between each other. Let's start with Cluster.

`Cluster` is set of observation data points which may have similar characteristics in some sense. Clustering is mainly method of unsupervised learning. To imagine easily - the map is set of clusters, grouping people by nationality, but as in ML, people may be scattered to other countries - which is normal till some grade.

if we take `distance` as distance between `clusters`, this term refers how far is cluster1's centroid from cluster2's centroid. Also term may refer to given point, by measuring distance from point to all clusters' centroids - where point would be owned by cluster with minimal distance.

In addition `dissimilarity` describers pretty same value as distance, it tells how datapoints are not similar to original centroid. Meaning that once distance is high - dissimilarity is also high, in my opinion - not sure about this one.

hope it helps.

Comment: Do you know where I can find any related document?

Comment: I found this pdf in my bookmarks related to this theme (https://www.umass.edu/landeco/teaching/multivariate/schedule/cluster1.pdf), but there is google and if you search for some tutorials there always would be some good stuff (some of them may be outdated but will give you chance to grab the context) - here is search link - (https://www.google.com/search?hs=9D0&ei=hJ1IW8ydEYvpUruDjYAD&q=machine+learning+cluster+definitive+guide&oq=machine+learning+cluster+definitive+guide&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l8.0.0.0.37840.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.pE0qX_EhxEs)